# How to include template file in ngcordova Isoffline()?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I am new to ionic app development . I am developing a app in which i am using ng Cordova network information plugin to check whether app is connected to internet or not . if internet is connected I want to display template file. is it possible to do it ?? if so how can I ??

```
if ($cordovaNetwork.isOffline()) {
       $ionicPopup.confirm({
                        title: "Internet Disconnected",
                        content: "The internet is disconnected on your device."
                    })
       ionic.Platform.exitApp()
```

Comment: what do u mean by "display template file"?and based on the result of network plugin you can do what ever you want...

Comment: instead of showing the message in popup i want show a template file(html file)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from run method, more info in [Ionic PopUp Service](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/)

```
.run(function($window, $rootScope, $cordovaNetwork, $ionicPopup) {
     if ($cordovaNetwork.isOffline()) {
            var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
            template: '<b>Hello!</b>',
            title: 'Internet lost',
            subTitle: 'Connection lost',
            scope: $scope,
            buttons: [
            { text: 'Cancel' }, {
                text: '<b>Ok</b>',
                type: 'button-positive',
                    onTap: function(e) {
                        //click Ok button
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
     }
 )}
```

OR

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/internet_info.html', {
    scope: $scope
}).then(function(modal) {
   $scope.modal = modal;
});

$scope.closeInternetInfo = function() {
  $scope.modal.hide();
};

// Open the login modal
$scope.OpenInternetInfo = function() {
  $scope.modal.show();
};
```

Your template should be something like this:

```
<ion-modal-view>
    <ion-header-bar>
        <h1 class="title">Internet</h1>
        <div class="buttons">
        </div>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>

    </ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>
```

Comment: instead of showing the message in popup i want to show a html file

Comment: You mean to display a popup but with a specific html template?

Comment: yes sioesi i want to display specific Html template

Comment: It must give a simple template to your popup, something like that .. I edit my answer.